# CSS3 navigation arrow

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation that looks like this:

[image]

The selected page has an orange arrow which i made it with an png image.My question is can i make that arrow with css/css3?
The code is:

```
nav ul li {
    display: block;
    padding: 25px 40px 25px;
}

nav ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}

nav ul li.selected a{
    color: #ef5a29;
}

nav ul li.selected{
    background-image: url('../img/arrow.png');
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to search for "css arrow"? there are a lot of examples

Comment: I saw this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ but didn't know how to implement it

Comment: please add your HTML code

Comment: create a fiddle of your code for make easy to implement that arrow in your code

Comment: this could be easyly googled: http://cssarrowplease.com/

that link you might find helpfull

Comment: This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SwN66/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some magic of the `:after` pseudo object, you don't even need to change the html markup =)

You could try something like that:

```
nav ul li.selected:after{
    content:'';
    float:right;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 16px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 16px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid #ef5a29;
}
```

or as I did in the jsfiddle below:

```
nav ul li.selected a:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    right:0;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 16px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 16px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid #ef5a29;
}
```

Note also that I moved the padding from `li` and added `display:block` to `a` for this example.

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zjn3Z/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much it worked :).One question why did you use content:''; ?

Comment: Glad to help! =) And to your question, `content` is a required property for pseudo objects `:before` and `:after`, they will not display if it is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes Absolutely you can make this triangle by css3 check this below links here is a good example 
http://mrcoles.com/blog/callout-box-css-border-triangles-cross-browser/

http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/

Comment: Thank you the links would be useful :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example you could use. You can change the .selected to :hover(or copy), to get a hover effect on it, maybe even with a different color on it.

```
<style>
a.selected .arrow-left{
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    /* Border top and bottom define the height of the arrow. */
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
    border-right:25px solid #EF5A29; /* The width of the arrow 25px and orange color */
    margin-left:10px; /* This so the arrow has some room from the text */ 
    display:block;
    float:right;
}
ul {
    border-right: 5px solid #EF5A29; /* The orange border */
    display:block;
    width:      150px; /* so it does not get 100% with automaticly */

}
li {
    list-style: none; /* Remove the list bullits */ 
}
li a{
    width:      150px;
    display:    block;
    padding-right:10px;
}
</style>
<ul>
<li><a class="selected">Home<span class="arrow-left"></span></a></li>
<li><a>Portfolio<span class="arrow-left"></span></a></li>
<li><a>About<span class="arrow-left"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No thats not what I am looking for

Comment: This could be exactly the same as the image you posted. only some small changes to color and padding and you will have the same result. What are you looking for then?

Comment: the answer that i accepted was what i was looking for.I upgraded your answer i could be useful but Martin Turjak answer was more elegant.Thanx for the answer